# Getting error while using MySQL as database in django

Tags: python, django, mysql-connector-python

I am using `Django 3.1.0` and I get the error below when I set `MySQL` as a database on **production server**.

```
#ERROR
Getting django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: mysqlclient 1.4.0 or newer is required; you have 0.10.1. error while using MySQL in Django
```

My server is an `apache server` and uses `Cpanel` and it is a python server, not a **vps** one.

I have tried installing `mysqlclient` and `PyMySQL` and adding the below code to the `__init__.py` file.

```
import pymysql
pymysql.version_info = (1, 3, 13, "final", 0)
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

and it is my DB config is Django

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'sadraedu_mydb',
        'USER': 'sadraedu_mydbu',
        'PASSWORD': '*******',
        'HOST': 'localhost', 
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error message does tell you what the problem is, you need to install a newer python library.

Comment: I have did it already but it didn't worked again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs because you are using PyMySQL as a replacement for mysqlclient (it's one or the other, you don't need both)

Django officially supports mysqlclient, but not PyMySQL (at time of writing, Dec 2020, Django 3.1)

Django has a check for the version of mysqlclient that you are using.

If you use PyMySQL as a replacement, it uses a completely different numbering system.

That's what causes this error.

"mysqlclient 1.4.0 or newer is required; you have 0.10.1."

In this example, it is telling you that it requires mysqlclient 1.4.0. But you are using pymysql 0.10.1.

If you want to use pymysql anyway, you need to fake the version number to bypass this error.

For example, when you set up pymysql as your drop-in replacement:

```
import pymysql
# because Django has a hard-coded check for mysqlclient version
# but we're using pymysql instead
pymysql.version_info = (1, 4, 0, "final", 0)
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue deploying my Django local app to Google Cloud.

Using Django 3.0 instead resolved the issue for me:

```
pip install Django==3.0
```

For some reason it did not recognise en-uk for `LANGUAGE_CODE` in `settings.py`, so I had to change that, but that was the only thing.